# Can zxing decode the QRCode in android like the picture below?

Tags: android, zxing

Can zxing decode QR Code like the picture below? If it can do it,can anybody give me a link or code?

[image]

Comment: yes... it can !

Comment: Yes i tried its working fine

Comment: Can you show me your decoding code?Thanks!